# RuntimeError: Type ‘Tuple when using Deep Markov Model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to use deep Markov Model on my dataset. However, when I use it I get the following run time error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F46GW.png)

My code is exactly similar to:

https://github.com/pyro-ppl/pyro/blob/dev/examples/dmm/dmm.py

I don't even understand what this error means. Has anyone seen this error before? Insights would be appreciated. This error occurs in guide function (line # 225) I think. But I don't know what is triggering this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that types for 2 last elements in your Tuple are int and float, while everything must be Tensor.

Probably the simplest way to fix is to make the int and the float (`mini_batch_seq_lengths` and `annealing_factor`, I believe) Tensors: change model to accept Tensor, and convert to/from scalars as needed.